Why does the `use` hook fetch twice?
Fetching data with the new React use hook makes three fetch requests to the server. Why?

Here's the code I'm using:
import { use, Suspense } from 'react'

const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  return res.json()
}

const JokeItem = () => {
  const joke = use(fetchData())
  return <h2>{joke.value}</h2>
}

export default function Joke() {
  return (
    <Suspense>
      <JokeItem /> 
    </Suspense>
  ) 
}

I did remove <React.StrictMode> from main.jsx, so its not that. I even did an npm run build followed by npm run preview to see the production build and it shows three times there as well.

You're calling fetchData again every time the component renders.

In your component, you're calling fetchData() directly inside use, which means the Promise is recreated on every render.
To avoid multiple fetches, you should move the Promise creation outside the component and pass it as a prop or memoize it.
as props:
import { use, Suspense } from 'react'

const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  return res.json()
}

const JokeItem = ({ jokePromise }) => {
  const joke = use(jokePromise)
  return <h2>{joke.value}</h2>
}

// This must be a server component
export default function Joke() {
  // You might declare this in the global scope as well
  const jokePromise = fetchData();
  return (
    <Suspense>
      <JokeItem jokePromise={jokePromise}/> 
    </Suspense>
  ) 
}

memoize:
...
const JokeItem = () => {
  const jokePromise = useMemo(() => fetchData(), []);
  const joke = use(jokePromise);
  return <h2>{joke.value}</h2>
}
...

source

This is great. Thanks! First, React 19 obviates the need for useMemo (and useCallback) bc the new compiler automatically memoizes. Second, passing it as a prop did reduce the number of calls from three to two. So it made a difference but not down to one.
I'd still love to know why there are multiple calls.

@Rap just edited, the promise inside JokeItem should not be called. Try this new version.

Yep. That did it. But only when I npm run build followed by npm run preview so that React.Strictmode doesn't render twice.
